# Java - Regex on a string to determine a date

Tags: java, regex, date

I'm a bit stumped with the most efficient way to approach this.

I have a large string of text and somewhere within this is the string `"Wednesday, April 3, 2013 from 9:00 AM to 6:00 PM"`.

I know the text will always be in this format but I need a way to extract this information from the string.  I'm thinking a regex would be the best bet but I don't know what will be before and after this string, I can't match on character count because months and days have different lengths.  Also the string could be any length.

I guess my question is, is there a regular expression I could use on this string to extract the date and time and would that be an efficient way to tackle this given the string could be anywhere from 1 to 10000+ characters?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat would be great for this particular scenario.  But in other sections of the code it will be matching the string for other substrings, not dates, with the regex provided through the frontend.

Comment: I think a classic [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) would be the best bet.

Comment: @sp00m - How is `SimpleDateFormat` going to help locate where in the text to use it?

Comment: I believe this question is netting downvotes because there are [hundreds of online references (link)](http://www.google.com/search?q=regex+date+format) for exactly these kinds of expressions (and your question doesn't show any prior research). In addition, asking what the most efficient method would be is impossible to answer as efficiency depends primarily on your environment and exact logic. Again, there are [a number of easily found resources (link)](http://www.google.com/search?q=regex+efficiency+java) online which detail regex efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Not the shortest regex but it works on you example:

```
((Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri|Satur|Sun)day, January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d+, \d{4} from \d+:\d+ [AP]M to \d+:\d+ [AP]M)
```

Comment: Much appreciated, similar to Ted's solution.. is this really the most efficient way though?  I'm trying my best to strip this string down in size removing unused parts to make it faster but it'll still be very slow.  I'm not knocking your answer, I'm just wondering if there's a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do something like this:

```
(Sunday|Monday|...), (January|February|...) [1-9][0-9]?, \d{4}
```

where you need to complete the `...` with the obvious lists (omitted for clarity). Also, you can tighten up the date and year syntax so you don't accept dates like April 43 or years like 0312. But if you can assume that the input is correct and you are just trying to locate it, then those steps are unnecessary.

Comment: This is probably the way to do it with Regex, but it'll be sooo slow.

Comment: I agree.  This is what I meant, this seems the only way but it'll be so slow..

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit permissive but should work in most cases:

```
String resultString = null;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\w+,\\s+\\w+\\s+\\d{1,2},\\s+\\d{4}\\s+from\\s+\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}\\s+AM\\s+to\\s+\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}\\s+PM)",
        Pattern.CANON_EQ | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        resultString = regexMatcher.group();
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

This one checks for month names and week day names:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("((?:Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday),\\s+(?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\\s+\\d{1,2},\\s+\\d{4}\\s+from\\s+\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}\\s+AM\\s+to\\s+\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}\\s+PM)",
        Pattern.CANON_EQ | Pattern.DOTALL);
```